# Sweeping the Duty Cycle of PWM with Prescalar enabled

Tags: pwm, verilog, peripheral, questasim

I have designed a PWM module in Verilog, and it contains a prescaler. I am updating the duty cycle register after each period completes (one duty cycle per period). I update the PWM registers on the clock (which is not prescaled), while the counter runs with the prescaler setting (when prescalar is enable). Now, my question is that I may miss some of the duty cycle values because my registers update quickly while the counter runs slowly. If I update PWM registers on the prescaled clock, it will occupy the bus. What could be the optimal design solution?

Comment: Utilize a FIFO buffer to store the updated duty cycle values. The buffer can hold multiple duty cycle values that are updated asynchronously. The PWM generator can then retrieve duty cycle values from the buffer as needed, ensuring that no updates are missed.

Comment: What should be the length of it? I thinking the same, but I believe the length of the FIFO is crucial given that my prescalar is 16 bits.

Comment: is there anyway to calculate the length of fifo? or we have to do hit and trial based on missing values of duty cycles?